# pass by object reference and pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python, if we run the following codes,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def f(df):
    df.set_index("a")
    df["c"] = 1

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 2), columns = ["a", "b"])
f(df)
print(df)
```

We get

```
           a         b  c
0   0.273589 -1.377437  1
1  -0.562968 -0.444558  1
2   1.627507 -0.958007  1
3  -0.006542  0.191644  1
4   0.719449 -1.522945  1
..       ...       ... ..
95 -0.159297 -1.464404  1
96  0.779439 -0.029497  1
97  3.549553  0.021404  1
98 -1.728806  1.150384  1
99 -1.676389  0.434420  1
```

We see that `reset_index` won't affect a `DataFrame` while assigning will affect. 

 In python, I know function should use call by object reference, which I didn't understand fully. I want anyone could help relate this concept to the above phenomenon I see in pandas, or, if I'm wrong, could point out the reason behind.

Comment: It has nothing to do with what you are seeing. `df.set_index` returns *a new data frame*, which you simply discarded. You need to use `df.set_index("a", inplace=True)`. On the other hand, `df["x"] = 1` will always work in-place.

Comment: @jezrael that won't work with this function, though, the OP would then have to return the new data-frame

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - yop, just tested. `inplace=True` is necessary here

Comment: @ jezrael I understood. Thanks